# Why can't my program see my resource dictionary?

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-4.0, resourcedictionary

In my program I **had** three functioning resource dictionaries for the languages that I allow the users to toggle during the running of my program. I simply want to move these dictionaries to a different folder in my project, but am having trouble. They are currently in the main project folder, but I would like to move them to my folder called "Language Resources".

The problem occurs in my `App.xaml` file where I set my start-up resource dictionary:

[image]

As you can see above, the program does not understand that I am telling it to look at the Language Resources folder for some reason...

Below is a screen cap of my solution explorer in VS for clarity:

[image]

What is the proper procedure to move these dictionaries to my desired folder?

Comment: Use Pack URI.. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Using `<ResourceDictionary Source="pack://Application:,,,/Language_Resources/LangenUS.xaml" />` does not run. What am I missing?

Comment: In your solution it is Language and Resources having space. But in the App.XAML it is having Underscore.

Comment: Good eye man! I thought that I needed the underscore in place of the space. It's working now. I appreciate it.

Comment: Added it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your solution there is a space between Language and Resources in the folder name. But in the App.XAML it is having Underscore.

It is always better to use Pack URI syntax when you try to use resources in XAML. Refer the MSDN link. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069(v=vs.110).aspx